# Get data from an Array in Vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

**Right now,** displayed data in my page is an array as per snippet below:
[image]

**But I want only** to get or display the project names.

**This is what I have only right now:**

```
fetch(context,id){
        if(context.getters['isEmpty']){
            Vue.api.mediasetting.index()
                .then(response=>{
                    var medias = response.data[key];

                    context.commit('setMedias',medias);
                    // console.log("init medias", medias[0].project_name)
                },response=>{

                });
        }
    },
```

**Can I** apply filter here and how? Thanks.

Comment: i think this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49485030/select-one-object-from-one-json-file-by-id-vue?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @loki I've already looked with that earlier, from what I have understood, they are only fetching a specific id. What I want is to get all project names. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: use Object.keys and filter "project name".

Comment: @HarshPatel I've tried this one : `context.commit('setMedias',this.medias.filter(function(project){
                                return project.project_name === project_name; 
                            })` but returns error: `app.js:100445 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined` Can you help me on this? Thanks.

Comment: can you make fiddle so I'll direct test the code?

Comment: @HarshPatel I'm sorry but I still don't know how to make a fiddle. But right now, I'm able to surpass it using a loop. I think filter is not working since I have an object arrays passed.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what html element you want to use for rendering the values, you may use a `v-for` [directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for) to rendering the project_name values:

```
<template>
  <ul id="example">
    <li v-for="(media) in medias">
      {{ media.project_name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

You are going to need to get the medias data from your store, you may get it using a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties):

```
<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    medias: function () {
      return this.$store.medias
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Example above is assuming you are using [single file component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) structure.

Comment: Mmm. unfortunately I'm not using a single file component structure.

Comment: Oh I see, then it should be something really similar, take a look to this example https://jsfiddle.net/ricardoorellana/mnp0vh4g/3/, you will need to change the hardcoded array with the data that comes from your store in your project

Comment: Okay. I've tried it but there's no data displayed anymore. Also have tried : `context.commit('setMedias',this.medias.filter(function(project){ return project.project_name === project_name; })` but returns error: `app.js:100445 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined ` Do you have any insights on this?

Comment: Mmmm, most likely you are accessing a wrong vuex state property key, check on your store the property name, I mean where you create the store instance `new Vuex.Store`

Comment: That error `Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined` means that you are trying to use the filter function on an `undefined` array, do this assigment first `var medias = response.data;` that should be the array, right?, then just print medias variable with a console.log(medias) to see if prints an array. After you test that, try to do the filter.

Comment: Variable `medias` already assigned to `response.data[key]`, but still returns an error and it even prints the array.

Comment: This is strange, let's try this remove the [key] when you do the assigment of the variable medias, so do this `var medias = response.data;`

Comment: I've already done that, but still doesn't work. This is really really really strange. HAHA

Comment: Yeah, mmm try to add your vuex store code on your question, so I can see how it is.

Comment: Weew, just used a for loop for it to solve. Returned value is an object array that's why filter is  not working.

Comment: Glad you make it work!, I recommend you analyse your solution to make even better and easy to maintain.